# How to get the right forms value from a button click

Tags: php, html, forms, input, hidden-field

## Overview of what my question is:

I have an array that is populated via XML inputs, and from this I am the using it to populate a web form with form controls. From here I want to be able to select the exact form that is clicked, but to do that I need to give the controls some form of unique identifier, which is an issue...

As the site is of a betting nature and I am currently working with horse racing, each horse is given a unique identifier by default, I have tried to add this identifier to the forms.
e.g:

```
<?php
//Values from feed examples: 123, 234, 345
$valuesFromFeed = array(123, 234, 345); //These are not in my code, they are values from the XML feed

while ($uniqueIdentifier = $valueFromFeed) {
    <form name="horse_<?php echo $uniqueIdentifier; ?>_frm" action="#">
        <input type="hidden" name="horse_<?php echo $uniqueIdentifier; ?>" />
        <input type="button" value="Place bet" />
    </form>
}
?>
```

But then the problem comes when I try to reference this name of "horse_123", I need to know exactly what the value of that name is, which is impossible as there are millions of horses, tracks and races.
Example of trying to get post:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['horse_' . $uniqueIdetifier])) {
    echo "You got the right thing here.";
} else {
    echo "Still no joy.";
}
?>
```

The issue with the code above, is that once the `$uniqueIdentifier` has been used in the while above, it is removed and is no longer usable in this scope.

## So to conclude, my point and question:

How do I get the correct name from the form in a submit for the specific horse that I wish to reference and get information on?

How do I use this information as I need to?

## Better Description:

I have been given an XML feed and site as part of a handover, this feed contains many hundreds of races and horses.
When this information is loaded into the page, it is also stored in a database on the server, as well as sending it through some different loops (which are messy, but someone else's code I'm trying to clean up!) which split it down and then make up a dynamic menu containing all the races, horses, odds and information. (All information on a single horse within a race is kept in one form)
Next to the information stated in the prior paragraph, is 2 buttons, one that allows the user to take odds and another that allows users to take starting price.
On either of these button clicks, I need the information attached to said horse, and then populate a betting slip. In the form (mentioned above) the name is `"horse_<?php echo $uniqueIdentifier; ?>_frm"`.
The problem that occurs to me is, yes data is stored on the server when it is loaded, that I cannot seem to get the right form via the unique identifier that is put into the form name

#### Edits

Added form surrounding my input as this is there, I just missed it in original question

Added the button that transmits data to where I need it

Added a better description of my problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple forms, one for each horse. Each form has a different action, where the URL includes the id of the horse. For example:

```
<form action="/horses/my_unique_horse_name">
  ...   
</form>

<form action="/horses/another_horse_name">
  ...   
</form>
```

Or you could have multiple forms all with the same action, with a hidden field for the name of the horse:

```
<form action="/horses/">
  <input type="hidden" value="my_unique_horse_name">
</form>

<form action="/horses/">
  <input type="hidden" value="another_horse_name">
</form>
```

Alternatively, you could have a button for each horse:

```
<form method="/horses/">
  <button type="submit" value="my_unique_horse_name">My Horse</button>
  <button type="submit" value="another_horse_name">Another Horse</button>
</form>
```

Beyond that, I don't entirely understand the problem. What kind of data are you submitting and retrieving?

Comment: At the minute, I am trying to receive all data attached to a horse such as the odds and place it is racing, the problem I am having is that I cannot get the right form without having a fully populated list in the POST check that contains all the horses id's

Comment: @SamuelGSwift You need to submit a list of all horse ids? Why are these not stored on the server? Also, if you're trying to receive data, it would normally be better to use a GET request rather than POST.

Comment: Due to client requests, I am obliged to keep all the data out of the URL, hence why a GET request would not be suitable, although I agree with you there, and storing the information still pulls me a large problem due to the fact that I have to have a list to loop through that contains many hundreds if not thousands, of pieces of information, slowing down the whole system, unless AJAX would be suitable for this?

Comment: Let's [talk about this in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74100/discussion-of-how-to-get-the-right-forms-value-from-a-button-click)

Comment: I'm afraid I can't due to the fact I do not have 20 rep :(

Comment: Argh! OK, so I don't really understand why you need to submit lots of horse IDs as part of the request. I would have thought the horse IDs would already be on the server, along with all the data about them, and then you're just requesting information about one horse as part of the request.

Comment: The trouble for me with going to the server, is that I have been given the code as part of a handover, I do not know where the guy who made it originally does this, or how (I have spent nearly a week trying to find the connection string to change it from mysql to mysqli!), and as part of the request, I just want to submit the one, to then use it's id to get all the other information associated with it

Comment: I will add a better description to the bottom of my question.

Comment: I have added the extra edit, I hope this helps understand what my problem is, sorry I haven't been very clear thus far

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not really getting it - I don't understand the relationship between the forms, the data on the server, and the data you want. Can you give an example of the HTML form as you have it (or want it to appear), the data you have on the server, and the data you want to retrieve.